# WINDOWS - Geth rinkeby account balance 0 when the balance has 9+ Ether

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, metamask, rinkeby, windows

So I've been using geth on windows in order to deploy my truffle project on the rinkeby testnet using an account where I have 9+ ether.

To get in sync with the chain I used (I previously added my account by using **./geth --rinkeby import account /pathoffile.txt**):

```
./geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal" --unlock="0x940c04c8d13b7abfd4704fe8a55794f0d5d48827"
```

So geth got in sync with the chain and I unlocked my rinkeby account that has the current balance (FYI that contract deployement was through remix nothing to do with the rest):
[Metamask balance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djv0u.png)

But when I use the console to check the balance with :

```
./geth --rinkeby attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

and later using

```
eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
```

I get a balance of 0 ...

I initially checked this because when I tried deploying my contract from truffle it said the gas limit has been exceeded but then I saw that the account that it was referencing had a balance of 0 so It could be because of that.

I could really need some help please, did I do somthing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure it finished syncing? What does `eth.blockNumber` return?

Comment: Pretty sure, it returned false

Comment: There are some cases where it will return false before finishing for example if geth can't find peers.

Comment: The block count was equal to the highest block (checked it compared to the rinkeby.io block)

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what is going on, if `eth.accounts[0]` is the correct address and your node si fully synced then it should show the correct balance.

Comment: From what I have read, maybe it wasn't fully synced, I tried it again and it didn't fully reach the end and was around 70 block behind permanantly. Since I didn't have much time to make the chain up to date I used infura instead of running my own node.

Comment: You may be affected by this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40070/geth-v1-8-unable-to-download-the-last-65-blocks-for-the-mainnet, it is good you found a solution.